# How rotate div without use "transform"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm using an extension from the SVG library to draw inside a div (https://sggjs.com/svg.draw.js/). However, it is possible to rotate it, using the "transform". Rotation is only visual, leaving the X and Y axes of the image unchanged, causing "svg.draw" to draw in the wrong coordinates when turned. How can I rotate by changing its axes to keep up with the rotation and get the right points to draw on the same rotated div? Thanks.

Edit: Adding code.

Function to draw:

```
drawImage = function (pointsRelative) {
        var pointsToDraw = $scope.getAbsolutePoints(pointsRelative)
        pointsToDraw = pointsToDraw.join()

        var draw = SVG('cutImage').size('100%', '100%')

        draw.polygon(pointsToDraw).attr({
            fill: '#3d7e9a',
            'fill-opacity': 0.4,
            stroke: '#3d7e9a',
            'stroke-width': 1
        })
    }
```

Function to get points created with mouse and convert to relative points:

```
getRelativePoints = function (clickPoints) {
        let conv = []
        for (let item of clickPoints) {
             let x = item[0] / parseInt(widthImage)
             let y = item[1] / parseInt(heigthImage)
             conv.push([x, y])
        }
        return conv
    }
```

Function to get relative points and convert to absolute points for draw image:

```
getAbsolutePoints = function (clickPoints) {
        let conv = []
        for (let item of clickPoints) {
            let x = item[0] * parseInt(widthImage)
            let y = item[1] * parseInt(heigthImage)
            conv.push([x, y])
        }
        return conv
    }
```

Exemple of HTML:
`<div id="cutImage" style="width: 300px; height: 800px;"></div>`

When I am add transform rotate 90deg, the div diplay, but your width and height continue the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you get points created with mouse. In the next example I draw an svg element inside a rotated div (`#wrap`). When you click on the svg element you get the mouse position on the console. Although the div is rotated the mouse position is where it should be on the svg canvas:

I hope this helps.

```js
function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}


svg.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
  let m = oMousePosSVG(e)
  console.log(m.x,m.y);  
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}

#wrap{
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but doesn't it that i need. My code do many things, i don't know how to explain and post it here...